# Comment multiple lines between two markers in a file

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a file like this

```
blah
blah
MARKER 1
blah
blah
blah
MARKER 2
blah
```

I want to find a single line command (awk? sed?) in bash to change it in

```
blah
blah
# MARKER 1
# blah
# blah
# blah
# MARKER 2
blah
```

Comment: This has been asked 100s of times. Did you make any attempt to search?

Comment: Is it always between `MARKER 1` and `MARKER 2` or there can be any other markers also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same in `sed`

```
$ sed '/^MARKER 1/,/^MARKER 2/s/^/#/' file

blah
blah
#MARKER 1
#blah
#blah
#blah
#MARKER 2
blah
```

Comment: I guess this can be used with sed -i ?

Answer (score 1):

Updated as per anubhava suggested :

```
awk '/^MARKER 1/,/^MARKER 2/{$0 = "#" $0} 1' testt
blah
blah
#MARKER 1
#blah
#blah
#blah
#MARKER 2
blah
```

Comment: ++ but consider `awk '/^MARKER 1/,/^MARKER 2/{$0 = "# " $0} 1' file`